# Twitter Bootstrap 3 form-horizontal collides with sidebar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want a horizontal form using bootstrap, but the second input is too wide, so it's below the sidebar. Why?

http://jsfiddle.net/58szw1w2/

The Markup:

```
<div id="sidebar">Sidebar</div>
<div id="content">
    Form from the <a href="http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-horizontal">example</a>
    <form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
          <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Email">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Password</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
          <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword3" placeholder="Password">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
          <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
              <input type="checkbox"> Remember me
            </label>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Sign in</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

The relevant CSS:

```
#content {
    width: 67%;
}

#sidebar {
    float: right;
    width: 33%;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: gold;
}
```

Comment: the reason SO requires code to be added here is for the event that JSFidle (or any other external resources) goes down. Trying to override that simple request while asking for help doesn't do much to your cause

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make the #content div float to the left to get everything to work see 
[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/58szw1w2/2/)

```
#content {
    width: 67%;
    float: left;
    padding-right: 10px;
}
```

Comment: @vico I agree with you